# C# Application Architecture - EF5 & understanding the Service Layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, service-layer

At work I've got thrown into developing a legacy enterprice application, that still is under production and stalled for the last few months because of bad design and instability.

So we've started using EF5 and applying some design patterns / layers to our application.

What I'm struggling to understand is: what exactly should the Service Layer do in our case? Would it be over-architecturing or would it provide some benefits without adding unneccesary comlexity?

Let's show you what we've got so far:

- we've introduced EF (Code First with POCOs) to map our legacy database (works reasonably well)
- we've created repositories for the most stuff we need in our new Data Layer (specific implementations, I don't see any kind of benefit regarding seperation of concern using generic repos..)

Now in the specific case it is about calculating prices for an article - either by getting a price from an arcile directly or from the group the article is in (if there is no price specified). It's getting a lot more complex, because there also are different pricelists involved (depending on the complete value of the order) and depending on the customer who also can have special prices etc.

So my main question is: **who is responsible for getting the correct price?**

My thoughts are:
The order has to know of the items it consists of. Those items on the other hand have to know what their price is, but the order must not know of how to calculate the item's price, just that it has to summarize their costs.

Excert of my code at the moment:

ArticlePrice (POCO, Mappings soon to be swapped by Fluid API)

```
[Table("artikeldaten_preise")]
public class ArticlePrice : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("einheit")]
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitId")]
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }

    [Column("preisliste")]
    public int PricelistId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PricelistId")]
    public virtual Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }

    [Column("artikel")]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }

    public PriceInfo PriceInfo { get; set; }

}
```

Article Price Repository:

```
   public class ArticlePriceRepository : CarpetFiveRepository
{
    public ArticlePriceRepository(CarpetFiveContext context) : base(context) {}

    public IEnumerable<ArticlePrice> FindByCriteria(ArticlePriceCriteria criteria)
    {
        var prices = from price in DbContext.ArticlePrices
                     where
                         price.PricelistId == criteria.Pricelist.Id
                         && price.ArticleId == criteria.Article.Id
                         && price.UnitId == criteria.Unit.Id
                         && price.Deleted == false
                     select price;

        return prices.ToList();
    }
}

public class ArticlePriceCriteria
{
    public Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }

    public ArticlePriceCriteria(Pricelist pricelist, Article article, Unit unit)
    {
        Pricelist = pricelist;
        Article = article;
        Unit = unit;
    }
}
```

PriceService (**does have a horriffic code smell...**)

```
public class PriceService
{
    private PricelistRepository _pricelistRepository;
    private ArticlePriceRepository _articlePriceRepository;
    private PriceGroupRepository _priceGroupRepository;

    public PriceService(PricelistRepository pricelistRepository, ArticlePriceRepository articlePriceRepository, PriceGroupRepository priceGroupRepository)
    {
        _pricelistRepository = pricelistRepository;
        _articlePriceRepository = articlePriceRepository;
        _priceGroupRepository = priceGroupRepository;
    }

    public double GetByArticle(Article article, Unit unit, double amount = 1, double orderValue = 0, DateTime dateTime = new DateTime())
    {
        var pricelists = _pricelistRepository.FindByDate(dateTime, orderValue);

        var articlePrices = new List<ArticlePrice>();

        foreach (var list in pricelists)
            articlePrices.AddRange(_articlePriceRepository.FindByCriteria(new ArticlePriceCriteria(list, article, unit)));

        double price = 0;
        double priceDiff = 0;

        foreach (var articlePrice in articlePrices)
        {
            switch (articlePrice.PriceInfo.Type)
            {
                    case PriceTypes.Absolute:
                        price = articlePrice.PriceInfo.Price;
                        break;
                    case PriceTypes.Difference:
                        priceDiff = priceDiff + articlePrice.PriceInfo.Price;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return (price + priceDiff) * amount;
    }

    public double GetByPriceGroup(PriceGroup priceGroup, Unit unit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("not implemented yet");
    }

    //etc. you'll get the point that this approach might be completely WRONG

}
```

My final questions are:
How do I correctly model my problem? Is it correct, that I am on my way of overarchitecturing my code? 
How would my Service Layer correctly look like? Would I rather have a ArticlePriceService, an ArticleGroupPriceService, etc.? But who would connect that pieces and calculate the correct price? Would that e.g. be the responsibility of an OrderItemService that has a method "GetPrice"? But then again the orderItemService would have to know about the other services..

Please try to provide me with possible solutions regarding architecture, and which object/layer does what.

Feel free to ask me additional questions if you need more info!

Comment: If you could reduce the size of your question to half or even third of your original question you would have get more people reading this...

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but I don't really see how I could cut it down without taking away important informations reagarding my questions :/

Answer (score 0):

You did present a simple scenario which the Repository itself might be sufficient. 
Do you have more repositories?
Do you expect you application to grow, and have more repositories in use?

Having a service layer that abstract the data layer is recommended and in use by most of the applications/examples that I have seen, and the overhead is not that significant.

One reason for using services might pop-up when you would like to fetch data from several different repositories, and then perform some kind of aggregation / manipulations on the data. 
A Service layer would then provide the manipulation logic, while the service consumer would not have to deal with several different repositories.
You should also think of situations where you might want to have more then one entity changed in one transaction (Meaning - more than one repository), and saving the changes to the DB only when all update actions where successful. 
That situation should imply using the [Unit Of Work Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx), and probably will conclude the use of a Service Layer, to enable proper unit-testing.

Comment: Well, in my scenario the price itself is calculated from different sources: it has to take into account the ArticlePrices, ArticleGroupPrices and CustomerPrices - which come from 3 different repositories. It also has to take into account from wich pricelist all of those are coming and it has to know which pricelist overrules the other..

Some of my concern is: my PriceService would have to know about all of those factors and how they are affecting each other..

Also: would I then have an OrderPriceService that knows about the ItemPriceService which knows about the (Article)PriceService?

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to design your system. It is very customary to have the Repository "JUST" fetch data, and a service layer that does all the logic. Also, as I wrote, you should think about possible UPDATE scenarios, and not just about data retrieval scenarios.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code at `PriceService`. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: The thing about the `PriceService` I don't like is, that it has to know about calculating the price for multiple targets. In the end I would have methods for things like `..ByArticle`, `ByOrder`, `ByGroup`, etc..

I would rather have some method like `Order.GetPrice()` that does something like `Sum(Articles.GetPrice(), DeliveryOptions.GetPrice())` etc.

Answer (score 0):

When i started with objects and architecture, my main problem was to give a good name to classes.

To me, it seems your service should be called "ShopService" (or something equivalent). Then your method GetByArticle, should be nammed GetPriceByArticle.

The idea of changing the name of the service for something bigger than just the price would be more meaningfull and would also address other issues (like your OrderPriceService you wonder about).

Maybe you can ask yourself "What is the name of my page or window that interracts with this service ?" Is there only one or more ? If more, what do they have in common ? 
This could help you figure out a good name for your service, and consequently different methods to acquire what each needs.

Tell me more. I will be please to help.